# Service implementing MessageCountListener not being notified on new email arrival

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I have implemented a service which retreives the inbox and implements the MessageCountListener interface for listening to new email arrivals.But on new email arrival, it does not gets notified! What may be the reason and what else can be done?
Here is the code:

```
public class EmailRetreiverService extends Service implements MessageCountListener{

public static final Vector v=new Vector();
public static final Vector nwmsg=new Vector();
Message[] m=null;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Log.d("EmailRetreiverStarted"," ");

    ConvertToSmtp cts=new ConvertToSmtp("myemail@gmail.com","mypassword"," "," "," ", " ");
    Folder folder=cts.retreiveInbox();
    try {
        m=folder.getMessages();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
        v.add(m[i]);

    }
    Log.d("EmailRetreiverMessageCount",new Integer(m.length).toString());
    Collections.reverse(v);
    /*folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter(){  

        public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {  
            Log.d("MessageListener","message listner invoked.");  
            Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages(); 
            TTSservice.say("Attention! "+msgs.length+" new messages have arrived now.Kindly retreive inbox again!");
            Collections.reverse(v);
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

                v.add(msgs[i]);

            //System.out.println("Got " + msgs.length + " new messages");  
            }  
            Collections.reverse(v);
            // Just dump out the new messages  

        }

    });*/
    folder.addMessageCountListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    v.removeAllElements();
}
@Override
public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("EmailService","MessageArrived!");
}
@Override
public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("EmailService","MessageRemoved!");
}
```

}
It must be noted that the service is successfully retreiving the inbox.But just does not get notified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do something to cause JavaMail to receive the notification from the server of new messages.  A simple approach is to call the getMessageCount() method periodically.  Another approach is to use the IMAP-specific idle() method, which requires dedicating a thread to calling that method.

Comment: I combined your two approaches."A simple approach is to call the getMessageCount() method periodically" and "dedicating a thread".So i used one and a half of your solution-i called getMessageCount() in a dedicated separate thread and it worked like a charm! Thanks! But why was the messageCountListener not getting called?

Comment: Because the server doesn't send the notification of the new message except as part of the response to a command, so you have to execute a command on the server to give it a chance to send the response.  JavaMail calls the listener when it sees that notification from the server.  The idle() method essentially executes a command that says "I'm sitting here doing nothing, you can tell me about new messages any time you want".